# Wrapping CSS3 Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

Within this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rZDpr/5/), I'm using CSS3 to slidein text (sample below). However, I'd like it to wrap around to effectively implement a ticker. Though the problem seems to involve micro-managing pixels to both add more text and create a clean transition.

```
@-webkit-keyframes slidein {
      from {
        margin-left:100%;
        width:100%
      }
      to {
        margin-left:0%;
        width:100%;
      }
    }
```

**Advice?**

Here is an [example](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/cut3.shtml), but I would like to use CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to get it done: http://jsfiddle.net/ytKV5/. Use Chrome.  I did not want to create code for every extension.

Keep in mind that from CSS you cannot adjust the speed of the slide based on the length of the scrolling text.  The longer the text, the faster it'll scroll.

HTML:

```
<div id = "wrapper">
    <h1>Scrolling text....scrolling...scrolling</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scroll-text {
    0% {
        left: 100%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);    
    }

    100% {
        left: 100%;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-150%);  
    }
}

#wrapper {
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    outline: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#wrapper > h1 {
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-animation: scroll-text 15s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: Can the text be wrapped around sooner? As implemented, the text doesn't loop back around until it has completely finished scrolling.

Comment: If you want the last word to be immediately followed by the first word, then I suppose you could take a look at 3D transforms.

Answer (score 0):

Booom your code here: [SmoothTextFlow](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_eirenaios/rZDpr/6/)

```
     h1 {
      -webkit-animation-duration: 15s;
      -webkit-animation-name: slidein;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: graysc;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidein {
      from {
        margin-left:100%;
        width:100%
      }
      to {
        margin-left:0%;
        width:100%;
      }
    }
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I had in mind. Here is an [example](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/cut3.shtml), but I would like to use CSS.

Comment: See updated code bro! its effective! more smooth! and clear what you want i dont understand! i ve just smoothen the transaction! anything else you need?